# showing functions are linearly independent subsets

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n$ be a positive integer and let $V_n$ be the vector space of polynomial functions (in $t$) from $F$ to $F$, where $F$ is some field.

Suppose also that $F$ has more than $n$ elements. Let $f_0, f_1, \ldots, f_n$ be distinct elements of $F$. We know that $V_n$ is spanned by $\{1,t,t^2,...,t^n\}$.

Show that the functions:

$$ A_0(t) = (t-f_1)(t-f_2)...(t-f_n) $$
$$ A_1(t) = (t-f_0)(t-f_2)...(t-f_n) $$
$$ A_2(t) = (t-f_0)(t-f_1)(t-f_3)...(t-f_n) $$
$$\vdots$$
$$ A_{n-1}(t) = (t-f_0)(t-f_1)...(t-f_{n-2})(t-f_n) $$
$$ A_n(t) = (t-f_0)(t-f_1)...(t-f_{n-1}) $$

are a linearly independent subset of $V_n$.

As for as this question goes, I am really stuck on getting started on it.  I know that a basis is a linearly independent subset of a vector space, but how do I go about showing those functions are basis of the vector space?  Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the linear map:
$$T(A)=(A(f_0),A(f_1),\ldots,A(f_n)).$$ If we let $a_i=A_i(f_i)$, which is non-zero since fields have no zero divisors, then it holds that
$$T(A_0)=(a_0,0,\ldots,0)$$
$$T(A_1)=(0,a_1,\ldots,0)$$
$$\vdots$$
$$T(A_n)=(0,0,\ldots,a_n)$$
which are very obviously linearly independent. Since $T$ is linear and the image of $A$ under it is independent, so must $A$ be independent. Moreover, if a linearly independent set is as large as another basis, it is a basis. (You could also note that the image of the $A$ under $T$ and that $T$ is a bijection)